# Theta Network (thetalab) : TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getChainId')

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is the official link of theta network

https://docs.thetatoken.org/docs/theta-js-sdk-getting-started#writing-to-the-blockchain

This below things i have require & config the Theta Network

```
require('isomorphic-fetch'); //In order to get fetch working in Node
const express = require("express");
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');

const thetajs = require("@thetalabs/theta-js");
const Wallet = thetajs.Wallet;
const chainId = thetajs.networks.ChainIds.Testnet;
const provider = new thetajs.providers.HttpProvider(chainId);
```

This is ths code I have implemented in Node Js

I want to do transaction from one theta account to another theta account using thetalab NPM package in Node JS.

**For Transaction we need sender private key, receiver public key, theta amount & tfuel amount**

```
        var privateKey = "0xf235351c3a8787121162e102dbc4cd79641441a8376dcb0ca46a71b78485c3eb"
        const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey);
        const address = wallet.address;
        const thetaWeiToSend = '0';
        const tfuelWeiToSend = '0.1'
        const transactionCount = await provider.getTransactionCount(address);       

        const from = address;
        const to = "0x02B74daDAd33040F16eB91d7Aafb1b181a3e7930";
        const txData = {
            sequence : transactionCount,
            from: from,
            outputs: [
                {
                    address: to,
                    thetaWei: thetaWeiToSend,
                    tfuelWei: tfuelWeiToSend,
                }
            ]
        }

        const transaction = new thetajs.transactions.SendTransaction(txData, chainId);
        console.log('transaction', transaction)
       
        const result = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
        console.log('result', result)
```

I get this error when i am trying to transfer THETA & TFUEL

```
fund Transfer error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getChainId')
at Wallet.getChainId (D:\Kartik\Theta\node_modules\@thetalabs\theta-js\dist\thetajs.cjs.js:1629:30)
at Wallet.signTransaction (D:\Kartik\Theta\node_modules\@thetalabs\theta-js\dist\thetajs.cjs.js:1648:37)
at Wallet.sendTransaction (D:\Kartik\Theta\node_modules\@thetalabs\theta-js\dist\thetajs.cjs.js:1421:31)
at fundTransfer (D:\Kartik\Theta\thetatransfer.js:49:37)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not providing the provider in the wallet make sure you must provide a provider in the wallet I am using the library for transfering the theta and tfule.

```js
const transfer = async (from, to, privateKey, thetaWeiToSend, tfuelWeiToSend) => {
    try {
        const wallet = new Wallet(privateKey, provider);
        const txData = {
            from: from,
            outputs: [
                {
                    address: to,
                    thetaWei: thetaWeiToSend,
                    tfuelWei: tfuelWeiToSend,
                }
            ]
        }
        const transaction = new SendTransaction.transactions.SendTransaction(txData);
        const result = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return error;
    }
}

const ten18 = (new BigNumber(10)).pow(18); // 10^18, 1 Theta = 10^18 ThetaWei, 1 Gamma = 10^ TFuelWei
const thetaWeiToSend = (new BigNumber(0));
const tfuelWeiToSend = (new BigNumber(1)).multipliedBy(ten18);

transfer('0xb66D945B021AcDE0Fc1c639616E1D3fC9Aa10584', '0x4E6CA5eCc47bA2dcDdd7A9961ED26f39e25Ab15c', '0x303bed7d1a962aed4e13536b8061e3e4232828ddd1e6b23abb6ab6d1400e034b', thetaWeiToSend, tfuelWeiToSend)
```